# Status bar not working on Ionic app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

As you can see here:
[image]

For some reason the status bar is "pushing" my fixed header a few pixels down. Is there any way to fix it?

I can't debug on browser because this issue happens only on the device.

I'm using the default Ionic app, and this is where I'm setting my StatusBar:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if(window.StatusBar){
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the status bar or simply merge navigation bar colour to status bar so nav bar looks big like other standard iOS apps?

Comment: I think the best option here is to always show the navigation bar.

Comment: Is your view controller embedded in `UINavigationController`? If not then you have to manually move your view controller 20 points up.

Comment: Could you post a link to the live webapp? Or even just a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Chuck I'm using the default Ionic App. I've updated my question with some code - everything else is the default settings.

Comment: Is your app have Cordova status bar plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Connect your phone to your computer and open google chrome and you see this route chrome://inspect/#devices

This allows you to debug the phone

I hope it helps you.

Sorry, the problem is IOS

http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/

it also for ios 9

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried also setting the app to fullscreen?

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

  if(window.StatusBar){
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
  }

  ionic.Platform.fullScreen();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix this with the correct configuration in your `config.xml`.
For further information see https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
```